# How can I get the correct select with criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have some related clases and I want to get a simple select if is made with sql 
I just want make `SELECT * FROM person WHERE id_person_type = 1`
But hibernate is bringing me another select 
I am using version `4.3.5.Final`

Here are my clases with less variables than the originals but with the relations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class Person  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private static final long serialVersionUID = -5504579691788263257L;
     private Integer idPerson;
     @NotNull
     private PersonType personType;
     @NotNull
     @Valid
     private Address address;

     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 2, max = 20)
     private String firstName;

     @NotNull
     @Valid
     private Set<PersonPhone> personPhones = new HashSet<PersonPhone>(0);

    public Person() {
    } 

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_person", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPerson() {
        return this.idPerson;
    }

    public void setIdPerson(Integer idPerson) {
        this.idPerson = idPerson;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_person_type", nullable=false)
    public PersonType getPersonType() {
        return this.personType;
    }

    public void setPersonType(PersonType personType) {
        this.personType = personType;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    @Column(name="first_name", length=20)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="person", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<PersonPhone> getPersonPhones() {
        return this.personPhones;
    }

    public void setPersonPhones(Set<PersonPhone> personPhones) {
        this.personPhones = personPhones;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="person_type"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class PersonType  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 2689950061291402765L;
     private Integer idPersonType;
     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 0, max = 15)
     private String name;
     private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>(0);

    public PersonType() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_person_type", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPersonType() {
        return this.idPersonType;
    }

    public void setIdPersonType(Integer idPersonType) {
        this.idPersonType = idPersonType;
    }


    @Column(name="name", nullable=false, length=15)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="personType")
    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return this.persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="address"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -3206021001369009888L;
     private Integer idAddress;
     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 1, max = 60)
     private String street;

     private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>(0);

    public Address() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_address", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdAddress() {
        return this.idAddress;
    }

    public void setIdAddress(Integer idAddress) {
        this.idAddress = idAddress;
    }


    @Column(name="street", nullable=false, length=60)
    public String getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="address")
    public Set<Person> getPersons() {
        return this.persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Set<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name="person_phone"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class PersonPhone  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 3677299664669135022L;
     private Integer idPersonPhone;
     private Person person;
     private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    public PersonPhone() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_person_phone", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPersonPhone() {
        return this.idPersonPhone;
    }

    public void setIdPersonPhone(Integer idPersonPhone) {
        this.idPersonPhone = idPersonPhone;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_person")
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="id_phone")
    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="phone_number"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class PhoneNumber  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 8490149919691287421L;
     private Integer idPhoneNumber;
     private PhoneType phoneType;
     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
     private String number;
     private Set<PersonPhone> personPhones = new HashSet<PersonPhone>(0);

    public PhoneNumber() {
    }


    public PhoneNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_phone_number", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPhoneNumber() {
        return this.idPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setIdPhoneNumber(Integer idPhoneNumber) {
        this.idPhoneNumber = idPhoneNumber;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_phone_type")
    public PhoneType getPhoneType() {
        return this.phoneType;
    }

    public void setPhoneType(PhoneType phoneType) {
        this.phoneType = phoneType;
    }


    @Column(name="number", nullable=false, length=20)
    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="phoneNumber")
    public Set<PersonPhone> getPersonPhones() {
        return this.personPhones;
    }

    public void setPersonPhones(Set<PersonPhone> personPhones) {
        this.personPhones = personPhones;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name="phone_type"
    ,catalog="htlsys"
)
public class PhoneType  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -7703414197297512412L;
     private Integer idPhoneType;
     @NotNull
     @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
     private String nameType;
     private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>(0);

    public PhoneType() {
    }

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id_phone_type", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPhoneType() {
        return this.idPhoneType;
    }

    public void setIdPhoneType(Integer idPhoneType) {
        this.idPhoneType = idPhoneType;
    }


    @Column(name="name_type", length=20)
    public String getNameType() {
        return this.nameType;
    }

    public void setNameType(String nameType) {
        this.nameType = nameType;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="phoneType")
    public Set<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return this.phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

**criteria**:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("personType.idPersonType", 1));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("surname"));
List<Person>  list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: "hibernate is bringing me another select" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: For example, in the table db there are only 3 rows, but the criteria is bringing me 5 rows repeating 3 times one of the inserted persons. Its clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("personType.idPersonType", 1));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("surname"))
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```